# HTML / JS Dropdown Menu Button doesn't drop in Android Studio WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want to have a Button which drops down some other options on an HTML file. I want to access this HTML from an Android WebView. Everything seems to be working as intended on my PC Browser but every time I try it in WebView it just shows the animation of the menu bars but doesn't drop down the unordered list.

This is how it looks on PC

```css
.header{
 background: #20211c;
}
.nav{
 padding-top:10px;

}
nav ul{
 position:absolute;
 color:#29B08E;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:wrap_content;
 transform-origin:top;
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(-90deg);
 transition:0.5s;

}
nav ul.active{
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg);
}

nav ul li{
list-style:none;
color:white;
background-color: #29B08E;
}
.dropdown{
 display: inline;
 padding-right:10px;
}

nav ul li a{
 display: block;
 color:white;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.inhalt{
 color:white;
}
.uberschrift{
 color:#CB4048;
}

button{
 font-family:tahoma;
 color:white;
 position:relative;
 width:wrap_content;
 height:wrap_content;
 front-size:24px;
 background:#20211c;
 border: 2px;
 border-color:white;
 box-shadow: none;
 outline: none;

}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE !html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <body>
<nav>
        <button>
         <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
         <p><strong>Menü</p>
         <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
         <div class="bar1"></div>
         <div class="bar2"></div>
         <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
        <script> function myFunction(x){
         x.classList.toggle("change");
        }
        </script></button>
        <ul>
        <li>Menu1</li>
        <li>Menu2</li>
        <li>Menu3</li>
        <li>Menu4</li>
        <li>Menu5</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("button").click(function(){
          $("nav ul").toggleClass("active");});});
         </script>
</nav>
      </body>
      </head>
      </html>
```

But as I said, on mobile it just does the animation.

Code of Android Studio:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String indexhtml ="file:///android_asset/index.html";
    webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wv_webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            Log.i("WebView", "Attempting to load URL: " + url);

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    WebSettings websetting = webView.getSettings();
    websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    websetting.getJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl(indexhtml);

}
}
```

Solved it myself,
had to give access to the android app via AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @Sandeep yes i did, i edited my android studio code into the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` into the AndroidManifest.xml